# How can I draw multiple scatter plots in the same cell, in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, graph, jupyter-notebook

I have 3 different dataframes and they all have a 'price' column. I want to have 3 different price to index scatter plots, but I don't want to have them on 3 different cells. I want them to be just in one cell, next to one another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do that in a single cell in Jupyter notebook.

This is probably not the most elegant way to do it, but you'll just need to structure your code so that you draw out each plot in order. e.g. create subplot1, add ticks, labels, etc... `plt.show()` it, then do the same for all the subsequent plots.

For example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# First plot
ax = plt.subplot()
plt.scatter( ... ) # Scatter plot 1 data
plt.title( ... )
plt.show()

# Second plot
ax = plt.subplot()
plt.scatter( ... ) # Scatter plot 2 data
plt.title( ... )
plt.show()

# Third plot
# Rinse and repeat
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the solution!